# NAT Overloading not working, access-list not catching ips?

Tags: cisco, routing, nat

I have a GNS3 lab set up and I am trying to get NAT overloading working with a dynamic pool. Please see diagram [image]

The issue I am having is traffic is being routed correctly from PC1 to the ISP1 or ISP2. However the translation I believe is not working because I see this on the ISP routers.

```
*Oct  7 16:14:46.211: ICMP: echo reply sent, src 1.1.1.2, dst 192.168.0.101, topology BASE, dscp 0 topoid 0
ISP1#
*Oct  7 16:14:48.211: ICMP: echo reply sent, src 1.1.1.2, dst 192.168.0.101, topology BASE, dscp 0 topoid 0
```

Here is my config from Edge1:

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 167.69.0.1 255.255.0.0

interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 media-type gbic
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 negotiation auto
!
interface POS1/0
 description "ISP1"
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
!
interface POS2/0
 description "ISP2"
 ip address 2.2.2.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside

router eigrp 1
 network 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
router bgp 10001
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 167.69.0.0
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 remote-as 65100
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 65200
 maximum-paths 2
 no auto-summary

ip nat pool overloadNAT 167.69.255.1 167.69.255.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside source list 100 pool overloadNAT

access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any log
access-list 100 permit icmp 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any log
```

Here is my show ip route from Edge1:

```
Edge1#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      1.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 3 masks
B        1.0.0.0/8 [20/0] via 1.1.1.2, 01:15:59
C        1.1.1.0/30 is directly connected, POS1/0
L        1.1.1.1/32 is directly connected, POS1/0
      2.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        2.2.2.0/30 is directly connected, POS2/0
L        2.2.2.1/32 is directly connected, POS2/0

      167.69.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        167.69.0.0/16 is directly connected, Loopback0
L        167.69.0.1/32 is directly connected, Loopback0
      172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        172.16.0.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L        172.16.0.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
D     192.168.0.0/24 [90/28416] via 172.16.0.3, 02:06:17, GigabitEthernet0/0
                     [90/28416] via 172.16.0.2, 02:06:17, GigabitEthernet0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

Extended ACL may work, but without "log" keyword:

> Q. Does Cisco IOS NAT support ACLs with a "log" keyword?
>   A. When you configure Cisco IOS NAT for dynamic NAT translation, an ACL is used to identify packets that can be translated. The current NAT architecture does not support ACLs with a "log" keyword.

More: [Network Address Translation (NAT) FAQ](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_q_and_a_item09186a00800e523b.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to change extended ACL to basic

```
access-list 10 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 11 permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255
```